# Update dynamically column header within Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I want to update the text of a column header based on the type of the object.  Let's say that I have objectA and objectB; if it is objectA I want it to appear in my second column as "A Version".  If it is not objectA (meaning its objectB) then update the same column but with " B Version" text.

I have in my .aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBillHeaders" OnItemDataBound="rptBillHeaders_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="98%" align="center" class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 1px #000000; border-top:none 0px #FFFFFF;">
                <tr class="gridHeaderRow">
                    <th>&nbsp</th>
                    <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="billVersionLabel" ></asp:Label></th>
                    <th>Action Type</th>
                    <th>Doc # </th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Developed By</th>
                    <th>Date Submitted</th>
                    <th>Date Processed</th>  
...
```

In my code-behind I have:

```
protected void rptBillHeaders_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater rptLineItems = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("rptLineItems"));
        rptLineItems.DataSource = currentBill.LineItemsByObjVersion[rowNumber].Sort(BillLineItem.SortColumn.LineItemNumber, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder.Ascending);
        rptLineItems.DataBind();
        rowNumber++;
    }       
        Control HeaderTemplate = rptBillHeaders.Controls[0].Controls[0];
        Label billVersionLabel = HeaderTemplate.FindControl("billVersionLabel") as Label;
        if (lit.BillTypes.ObjA == "A")
        {
            billVersionLabel.Text = " A Version";
        }
        else if (lit.BillTypes.ObjB == "B")
        {
            billVersionLabel.Text = " B Version";
        }

}
```

It might be easy to do, but I'm learning ASP.NET.  Therefore, I researched on how to developed it and this has this [tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Find-and-access-controls-in-ASPNet-Repeater-Header-and-Footer-Template.aspx) was the one I tried to implement in my solution.

So far no changes appears in when I run the web application.

Thanks in advance.

NM

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the method and see what is happening?  There are a few different possible issues so you need to narrow down exactly which part of your code is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Actually, this comment is the answer.  Can you suggest the same in the answer question? .  I deleted the breakpoint and that made the table to populate correctly.  Thanks @AdamHeeg.

Comment: I would gladly, but I must confess I'm not sure how deleting a breakpoint would fix any issue?!  Are you saying the program was stuck on the breakpoint and you didn't notice at first?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect exactly the suggested changed that allowed the label to be seen as I wanted.  

In summary; the control has to be specified as  "rptBillHeaders.Controls[0].Controls[0];" (Two zeros), and don't put a </br> tag within the text.